# How can i make my comments field allow images as part of the comment? (drupal 7)

Tags: media, comments

I would like to allow users to put images into their comments but I can't seem to find a module or anyone who has done such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module. Using this module you can use pictures in comments also

> This module will allow Drupal to replace textarea fields with the CKEditor - a visual HTML editor, usually called a WYSIWYG editor. This HTML text editor brings many of the powerful WYSIWYG editing functions of known desktop editors like Word to the web. It's very fast and doesn't require any kind of installation on the client computer.

Comment: Thanks that snapped on like a dream, tho i am worried about the security implications of allowing users to run html or javascript is there a way to turn these features off?

Comment: @Plentybinary YOu can give permissions to only trusted users;You can create profile on ckeditor/own text formats

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce)! It's very easy to use. But let me tell you that this only works for inserting and formatting the image inside a comment. If you want images to be comments you'll have to create a custom module (I am working on this right now).